# Solving 4 coupled differential equation and minimizing the solution

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I have a system of $4$ coupled differential equations.

```
a = a1 + g (1 - Cos[(2 Pi z)/h]); k = 96.29333; b1 = 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (Pi/a)^2]; b2 = 
 Sqrt[k^2 - (3 Pi/a)^2]; Z1 = (w c)/b1; Z2 = (w c)/b2; s =3.5 h; c = 
 1.257 10^-6; w = 2.8888 10^10;

With[{a = a1 + g (1 - Cos[(2 Pi z)/h]), k = 96.29333, 
      b1 = Sqrt[k^2 - (Pi/a)^2], b2 = Sqrt[k^2 - (3 Pi/a)^2], 
      Z1 = (w c)/b1, Z2 = (w c)/b2, s = 3.5 h, c = 1.257 10^-6, 
      w = 2.8888 10^10}, 
     sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[z] == -I b1 x[z] - 
          0.5 D[Log[Z1], z] y[z] + 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) u[z] + 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) v[z], 
        y'[z] == 
         I b1 y[z] - 0.5 D[Log[Z1], z] x[z] + 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) v[z] + 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) u[z], 
        u'[z] == -I b2 u[z] - 0.5 D[Log[Z2], z] v[z] - 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) x[z] + 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) y[z], 
        v'[z] == 
         I b2 v[z] - 0.5 D[Log[Z2], z] u[z] - 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 + b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) y[z] + 
          0.375 (D[Log[a], z]) ((b1 - b2)/(Sqrt[b1 b2])) x[z], x[0] == 1, 
        y[s] == 0, u[0] == 0, v[s] == 0}, {x, y, u, v}, {z, .1, 1}, {a1, 
        g, h}]]
```

This gave me the solutions.But, I need to use some combinations of these solutions like:

```
F = x[z] Conjugate[x[z]];
G = u[z] Conjugate[u[z]];
K = y[z] Conjugate[y[z]];
L = v[z] Conjugate[v[z]];
J = F/(K + L + G + F)
```

Now I have to minimize `J` with respect to `a1,g,h` and `z` for the given range of parameters.For that I used `FindMinimum[]`. But I got some errors...

```
FindMinimum[{J /. sol, .1 <= a1 <= .2, .02 <= g <= .03, .15 <= 
   h <= .16, .1 <= z <= .6}, {a1, g, h, z}]
```

These are the errors:-

> ParametricNDSolve::fpct: Too many parameters in {a1,g,h} to be filled from {0.55}. >>
>   ParametricNDSolve::fpct: Too many parameters in {a1,g,h} to be filled from {0.55}. >>
>   ParametricNDSolve::fpct: Too many parameters in {a1,g,h} to be filled from {0.55}. >>
>   General::stop: Further output of ParametricNDSolve::fpct will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>   FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value (1/<<1>>)Conjugate[ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],1,1,{<<1>>},{NDSolve`base$27605,NDSolve`NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolve,Internal`Bag[<2>]},<<6>>,{},All]}][0.55]] <<1>>[<<19>>] is not a real number at {a1,g,h,z} = {0.19,0.029,0.159,0.55}. >>

Could you please help me to resolve this....
Also,in order to make sure that the solution of differential equations is correct, I just tried to plot the function J for a particular value of a1,g and h with z ranging from 0.1 to 0.6 using:

```
W1 = Plot[Evaluate[J /. sol], {z, .1, .6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

I then got a fine graph also. But I have to minimize this function J w.r.t these four variables.Please help me to solve this.....